# How to get latitude and longitude of a user's location in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am a new in Swift and I need to get the current location of a user. I mean that I need to get latitude and longitude. I have tried this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if (error != nil) {
                println("ERROR:" + error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            } else {
                println("Error with data")
            }
        })
    }

    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark) {
        //  self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        println(placemark.locality)
        println(placemark.postalCode)
        println(placemark.administrativeArea)
        println(placemark.country)
        println(placemark.location)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        println("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

And here I can get coordinates, but it will looks like:

> <+55.75590390,+37.61744720> +/- 100.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/14/15, 10:48:14 AM Moscow Standard Time

How can I retrieve only latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code updated for Swift 3.x and Swift 4.x

As I can see you have used `print(placemark.location)` in your code.

So if you want to get only latitude use this code

```
print(placemark.location.coordinate.latitude)
```

and if you want to get only longitude use this code

```
print(placemark.location.coordinate.longitude)
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 2):

You can expect multiple calls to `didUpdateLocations` with accuracy improving over time (assuming you are in a local where the GPS can get good reception - outdoors, not surrounded by tall buildings).   You can access the latitude and longitude directly from the CLLocation objects that are in the `locations` array.

```
let location = locations[locations.count-1] as CLLocation;
println("\(location.latitude) \(location.longitude)");
```

Answer (score 1):

`func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)`

Your `locations:[AnyObject]!` actually is an `[CLLocation]`
just get its last object and use CLLocation's `coordinate` property.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html

Comment: Well, now I need to get the street name and the number of the nearest building. How can I do so?

Comment: I dont know how to do that with MapKit, I use google map sdk. Here's the thing, you have to get address of your desired location (CLPlaceMark maybe ?) and extract these data, or they are even extracted for you.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/index.html